Are algorithm proof-check questions on-topic?
Some simple algorithms are easy to review, plus them often being devised by amateurs, errors are easy to find.
By my case is a bit complicated. First, my algorithm is one for parsing languages using context-free grammar without building a table (directly doing so off the grammar spec), that alone is too much work for most of us. Second, such algorithm need gigantic number of test cases to verify its robustness.
Q1: would such question be on-topic eventhough nobody would bother to answer it?
Q2: I'd like to solicit advice on how to verify complex algorithms like mine, to improve it and ultimately make it fully functional.

I'm not 100% sure, but based on what you've provided here, I expect that it is on-topic, but might or might not receive any engagement.
There are two questions: is it on-topic?  and, is it a good question?  (i.e., a good fit for our mission/format/etc.)
On-topic: If it is asking us to check your code/implementation, it is probably off-topic here.  If it is asking us to check whether your algorithm is correct (e.g., based on pseudocode or a mathematical specification), that is on-topic here.
Good fit: The question to ask yourself is, will this be likely to be useful to others in the future?  We're hoping to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to many people, in the form of questions and answers.  If you are the only one this will be useful to, then it might not receive much of a positive reception here.  Also, our site format is designed for questions and answers that can be explained in a few paragraphs.  If the question is very long, maybe nobody will read it; and if answering it takes a lot of work, that might be too much to expect for our site format.
The normal way to verify complex algorithms is using a mathematical proof, e.g., manual proof (invariants, etc.) or through formal verification.  Most algorithms textbooks contain many examples of such proofs.  See also Formal program verification in practice and Why is writing down mathematical proofs more fault-proof than writing computer code? and Why are mathematical proofs so hard? and Program Correctness, The specification.  However, proving a complex algorithm correct might indeed be a challenging task, especially when the task itself is non-trivial.
